# CodeIgniter Active Record removing special characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, encoding

I'm new to CodeIgniter and have come into an issue with the insertion of special characters into the MySQL database.
I am inserting data into the db using this code:

```
return $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

When I view the text in the db, all '€' signs are changed to '?' signs. Also, there was a sentence with 'á' in it and it was removed, and all text after it was not inserted into the db.

I did a var_dump on *$data* just before the insert and the characters are correct.

The MySQL collation for the field is **latin1_swedish_ci**.
I changed it to **utf8_general_ci** to see if it would make a different but then the '€' sign was completely omitted.

**SOLUTION**:
Before the db insert, set the charset to **latin1**:

```
$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
return $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

Another solution was to change the CodeIgniter database file (*config/database.php*). The code should read:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

Comment: how are you "viewing" the text in the DB, my guess is either the browser encoding, or something to do with phpmyadmin/your console, dump the row to a screen and see if it comes out correctly from a query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your charset configured to in the config/database.php file? [See here for info on database config file.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

EDIT:

Also look at this [definitive guide to UTF-8 and CI](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/08/utf-8-support-for-codeigniter).

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci his question was a bit unclear but i think thats what he was using before changing to utf8_general_ci - could be wrong

Comment: `$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';`

I changed the db collation to match **utf8_general_ci** and it didn't change anything. I am viewing the text in the db using phpMyAdmin

Comment: I've changed **$db['default']['dbcollat']** to **latin1_swedish_ci** and now I get **?** for any symbol it doesn't recognise -- such as á and €

Comment: Did you go through all stages in the second link I posted?

Comment: @msanders: I followed all of the steps except for those in sections 'Set the HTTP header in index.php' and 'And finally, set up your Meta Data'. All of the charsets are set to utf8, and the collations are set to utf8_unicode_ci. It is still omitting the text after the € sign and the á.

Comment: :( Will have a look at this properly when I get back home. But first, I see that you are `var_dump`ing the data before it goes into the active record function, could you echo out the last run query after the active record call too. To do this use `$this->db->last_query();`. This will let us know if CI active record is messing it up, or whether it is mysql. Then we can point the finger :)

Comment: I echoed `$this->db->last_query()` and it displayed the € sign and the á correctly. I inserted the value **a€b€cád**. It appears exactly as is, when echoed with `$this->db->last_query()`. In the database, as **latin1_swedish_ci**, it shows as **a?b?c**. As **utf8_unicode_ci**, it showed as just **a**. I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: Ok, I downloaded CI and setup a quick test site to replicate your issue. I ran through the two links I posted but still got your issue. but I managed to find a work around, prior to executing `$this->db->insert(...);` do `$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");`. Then it all seems to work. There must be a better way to do this but I'll leave you find that :)

Comment: @msanders: Thank you very much! This worked for me: `$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");`. I read more about the `SET NAMES` query and realised that it sets the client side charset. So I changed my `config/database.php` file in CodeIgniter to `$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';` which also worked. Again, thank you for your time with helping me to resolve this!